# Using MCU's internal flash memory as FatFs drive

Tags: stm32, fat, flash-memory

I'm trying to make internal flash on STM32F051xx to be seen as a drive.

This is the code on the top level:

```
char USER_Path[4]; /* USER logical drive path */
FATFS USER_FatFs;  /* File system object for User logical drive */
FIL USER_File;     /* File object */  

uint32_t bytesWritten;
uint8_t text[] = "Text to write to logical disk";
if (FATFS_LinkDriver(&USER_Driver, USER_Path) == 0) {
  if(f_mount(&USER_FatFs, (TCHAR const*)USER_Path, 0) == FR_OK) {
    if(f_open(&USER_File, "STM32.TXT", FA_CREATE_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE) == FR_OK) {
      if(f_write(&USER_File, text, sizeof(text), (void *)&bytesWritten) == FR_OK); {
        f_close(&USER_File);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

f_mount() returns FR_OK, but when it comes to creating a new file via f_open(), which calls find_volume(), which calls check_fs() which returns FR_NO_FILESYSTEM. I assume this is because a boot sector wasn't created, but I have no idea how to do that.

I've written USER_read(), USER_write() and USER_ioctl() functions, but I don't know what to write in the USER_initialize() function. Right now I've left it in it's original state, where it returns RES_OK without doing anything. I feel like that may be the source of the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and what it comes down to is that there simply isn't enough space in internal flash memory (64KB total) to have it used for FAT.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's not going to work very well after all. My suggestion would be to reconsider the generality of idea.

FatFS works with a block device in which it can write any 512-byte sector of the disk at any time. But that's not how STM32 flash memories work. In STM32 series, flash memory is organized as a set of 1-2-4-16-64-128 KB sectors! (clearly not 512-byte sectors assumed by FatFS). Each sector would be needed to be written to as part of a program/erase cycle.

Writing to a single 512-byte subsector of those STM32 flash sectors will require an expensive, slow operation where you'll have to erase the entire flash sector, then re-write it with one 512 sector modified! On a 128KB sector it could take up to 4 seconds to just erase the sector! This will wear the flash memory very quickly, resulting in progressive failure of the NOR flash.